# Website default document denied by security restrictions?

Tags: web-hosting, security, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 website hosted at winhost.com.

The default document is index.html. In the browser address bar, if I enter

http://www.mysite.com/index.html

it works fine - I get the index.html page as desired.

If, however, I simply enter http://www.mysite.com

the site behaves as if I have requested a page allowed only to authenticated users, that is, I am automatically redirected to the Login.aspx page.

Obviously this is a major panic! It means that the normal, public facing portion of the site is no longer visible unless visitors are instructed to include "index.html".

In IIS, I have verified that the "Default Document" is index.html, and it is first in the list.

In the web.config, I tried adding

```
<location path="index.html">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But that did not help.

This all happened when I converted the site from 2.0 to 4.0. I was so busy fixing all the other problems (ajax security, wrong versions of dlls, etc.) that I never noticed this problem. Seems like it should be simple to fix, but I am stumped. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It could be your ASP.NET routing that kicks in when no real file is specified (URL that points to existing file/folder). Too bad I'm not a .NET guy to give you more useful idea/advice. But you can try creating custom URL Rewrite rule that will redirect request to the root folder (request without `index.html`) and redirect it to the URL with `/index.html`.

Comment: Could you show us your entire system.web section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the NTFS permissions for the **folder**, where your website is located. And compare it with "index.htm" **file** permissions. Some user account must be missing.